# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^5 |y_n|^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose, that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^8, \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n|^8$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^4 |y_n|^2$, where $x_n$ and $y_n \in \mathbb{C}$, are convergent series.

> What can I say about the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^5 |y_n|^2$?

$|x_n| \to 0$, otherwise the fisrt series would diverge. Thus there is an integer $N >0$ such that $\forall n > N \ \ ( |x_n| < 1 )$ and $|x_n|^5|y_n|^2$ converges to $0$ faster then $|x_n|^4 |y_n|^2$. So I assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^5 |y_n|^2$ is also convergent, but how can I show that more formally?

I tried to use the Hölder's inequality:
$||x^4 y^2 x ||_1 \leq ||x^4||_2 ||y^2||_4 ||x||_4 = ||x||^4_8 ||y||^2_8 ||x||_4$. From the first two series follows, that $||x||^4_8 <\infty$ and $||y||^2_8 < \infty$, but I cannot say anything about $||x||_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $|x_n|^5|y_n|^2 = |x_n|^3 (|x_n|^2|y_n|) |y_n|$ and apply the three-term Holder inequality with exponents $8/3$, $2$, and $8$.

Comment: It was so simple) Thanks!